# Refresh Dynamics CRM 2013 grid from aspx modal page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, dynamics-crm

I am trying to write a custom plugin for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013.  We are running On Premises.  I created a custom c# web project to add Products to a Quote more quickly.  The web page is launched as a modal page from the ribbon. (I used the Ribbon Workbench 2013).  All back-end functionality works fine on the new modal form, but as I add Products to the Quote I would like the Product sub-grid on the Quote form to refresh Automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "refresh" method of "Xrm.Page.ui.controls"?

Like:

```
var ctrl = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("SubGridName");
ctrl.refresh();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx

By clicking a button you must execute a custom javascript code. After closing modal window add code specified above.

UPD.

1) We need to create "JScript" web resource ("/script/myCustomScript.js")

Like that:

```
function onClickRibbonButton1()
{    
    // show modal dialog
    window.showModalDialog('https://serverurl/custompage.html');
    // after closing - refresh sub grid
    var ctrl = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("SubGridName");
    ctrl.refresh(); 
}
```

2) In Workbench specify following:

[image: Ribbon Workbench]

Comment: Yes, I cannot directly access the 'Xrm' property. I have tried caller.Xrm and parent.Xrm without any luck.

Comment: Where are you placing javascript code? On custom web page?

Comment: Yes Mikhail that is correct.  The script should be called just after a record is created from my custom web page (shown as a modal dialog)

Comment: Ok, Christo, i understood. You doing wrong. Tomorrow i will edit my answer to specify more details.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately this does not answer my question.  I need to refresh from my custom page each time a record is added.  My custom page must not close after the record is added - a user should be able to add products multiple times.  The command needs to be triggered from the custom page.  If the custom page can call the registered javascript that will also work.